# AngularJS - show $index as char

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat which repeats two `<li>` s a particular number of time.  I am also using the `$index` to see which index the outputted `<li>` is.

A sample is on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/cHQLH

However, I need that one of the `<li>`s when using the index rather than outputting numbers like 1, 2, 3 etc, it outputs letters like A, B, C and so on.

Is there a way to do this in AngularJS?  I am new to this.

EDIT:

I need that the output would be in the following way:
C1, C2, C3....
B1, B2, B3....
A1, A2, A3...

i.e. the letters are descending.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can write a filter:

```
.filter('character',function(){
    return function(input){
        return String.fromCharCode(64 + parseInt(input,10));
    };
});
```

and use it:

```
{{$index+1|character}}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/65FMq/)

Comment: thanks for the demo.  Is there a way to concatenate the indexes together so I get something like 

A1, A2, A3....
B1, B2, B3....
C1, C2, C3... 

I have updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/65FMq/1/) but for some reason cannot get them in the above format, but rather 

A1, B2, C3...
A1, B2, C3...
A1, B2, C3...
...

Comment: @user1809790 is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/65FMq/2/) what you want? I have changed `$index+1` to `$parent.$index+1`.

Comment: how easy is it to change the order of the index to obtain something like: C1, C2, C3 B1, B2, B3 A1, A2, A3 (i.e. change the order of the letters from ascending to descending)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really angular specific but you could easily define a function that converts from the number (index) to the letter that you want. I am assuming ASCII characters here and defined the following function:

```
$scope.getLetter = function (index) {
    return String.fromCharCode(65 + index);
}
```

To print this out, then all you need to do is:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myOtherNumber)"><span>{{getLetter($index)}}</span></li>
```

To see this all working, take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vd4Z4/

Comment: I have updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/vd4Z4/1/).  Basically what I need to do is give each cell a combination of letter and number.  I want the cells to have IDs in the following fashion:

A1, A2, A3....
B1, B2, B3....
C1, C2, C3... 

At the moment I am getting 

A1, B2, C3
A1, B2, C3
A1, B2, C3

Is it possible to make them in the format above?